# C-c C-r to see the effect of a change in equation

Tags: auctex, viewers

I am recently experimenting with Auctex and preview-latex, I read the quick-start part of Auctex documentation.

I have a question on C-c C-r, I created a simple test document and therein I am changing a symbol in an align environment and running C-c C-r on this selected align region(which is the equation), however after successful compilation, this change is not reflected on the output dvi, I have to run C-c C-c once more to see the change on the dvi output, where am I mistaken about C-c C-r?

I am trying to interactively see the changes on the other screen over the dvi output with C-c C-r, is this reasoning wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing to do with emacs, but rather to your .dvi viewer. For the change to be visible, it has to refresh the displayed file.

You can do that in a few different ways :

- reopen the dvi viewer with the new file (that's what a second `C-c C-r` keypress will do);
- find the `refresh` button in your viewer interface;
- have a viewer which performs automatic refresh when it detects that the file has been changed.

Comment: what is the answer to the last option?

Comment: I don't use .dvi, so I can't advise you about that. I know evince does it for .pdf files though, so it may work for .dvi as well.

Answer (score 1):

C-c C-r has nothing to do with preview-latex: it is the region-equivalent of C-c C-c, both compile for "normal" viewing.

At least in my installation, all preview-latex keyboard shortcuts start with C-c C-p. The environment-toggle is C-c C-p C-e. I suggest that you check your menu --- the keybindings are listed there.

Comment: why? I do not get it... I would like to make a change on one equation, and C-c C-r that equation only, apparently C-c C-r does that, but why is not that reflected on the viewer?

Comment: Just to be sure: are you trying to see the output within Emacs or in an external viewer?

Comment: external evince or xdvik, but I guess I did what i want to to if i compile the region with C-c C-r then view this with C-c C-v I get the view of the compiled region *only*, partially what I want, however the whole document is not updated as you do as in C-c C-c

Comment: Then I'm reiterating: this has nothing to do with preview-latex. (I hope that the other answer got your problem right!)